# IBM WebSphere Server JVM properties

Tags: jvm, websphere

There are certain JVM properties (such as timezone) which can be changed by application deployed on WebSphere server. Such changes affects all the application on that server. Is there a way by which we can prevent applications from changing JVM properties at runtime. I am wondering if we can set some property in WebSphere server which will then prevents applications changing anything on JVM at runtime. Its like having JVM properties controlled by IBM WebSphere server rather than applications deployed on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent applications from setting JVM system properties at runtime by enabling Java 2 security on the application server and then ensuring none of the deployed applications is configured with a [Java 2 security policy file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_dynamic.html) that grants the [java.util.PropertyPermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#PropertyPermission), specifically the "write" action, for any property.

Comment: thanks Dave. Just tested with main(). Will run with WebSpeher now.